When I create a new flutter project these 2 errors are showing
These two errors are shown for main.dart:

Invalid constant value.
Undefined name 'Icons'.

And I get these two errors for widget_test.dart:

Undefined name 'Icons'.
Unused import: 'package:flutter/material.dart'.



What is the main issue and how can I solve this?

run flutter doctor and tell any errors.
